# Forwarding email is the same as sending?

Tags: email

The objective of my mail server is primarily forwarding emails (after spam filter), so I wonder if I'd still have issues that are related to 'sending' emails over SMTP?

To put it another way, is forwarding the same as 'sending' email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix forwarding and relaying. Forward occurs when received and delivered message is sended by MUA to another address. Relaying occurs when MTA direct the undelivered message to another MTA for further processing.

Comment: So what mail delivery solutions (mailchimp, sendgrid, mailgun ..) do is MTA to MTA or?

Comment: ... and forwarding is MUA -> MTA -> MTA -> MUA ?

Comment: Relaying is MTA -> MTA, yes. And Forwarding goes from MUA to MTA, just like sending.